# How to sort values of nested dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

This is my code at the moment but I have to sort the sections in alphabetical order and the id numbers in ascending order. Does anyone know where and how I can insert the .sort/.sorted function here?

```
class_lists = {}
class_sections = {}

for i in student_data:
    for j in i['enlistment']:
        if j['course code'] not in class_lists.keys():
            class_lists[j['course code']] = [{"section":j['section'],'class list':[i['id']]}]
            class_sections[j['course code']] = [j['section']]
        else:
            if j['section'] in class_sections[j['course code']]:
                index_ = class_sections[j['course code']].index(j['section'])
                class_lists[j['course code']][index_]['class list'].append(i['id'])
            else:
                class_lists[j['course code']].append({"section":j['section'],'class list':[i['id']]})
                class_sections[j['course code']].append(j['section'])
```

```
>>> print{class_lists}
{'UK 60': [
    {
      'section': 'B', 
      'class list': [
           '201007', 
           '201005', 
           '211008',
       ]
     },
     {
       'section': 'A', 
       'class list': [
           '201077', 
           '201065', 
           '211088',
       ]
     }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort all the lists after you've built them rather than trying to do it as you go:

```
for sections in class_lists.values():
    sections.sort(key=lambda s: s['section'])
    for section in sections:
        section['class_list'].sort()
```

Comment: This is a good solution, however, `section['class_list'].sort()` doesn't treat ids as numbers. You should add a `key=int` to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort them this way:

```
class_lists['UK 60'] = sorted(class_lists['UK 60'], key=lambda item: item['section'])
for section in class_lists['UK 60']:
    section['class list'].sort()
```